# Why layout RFC not working in nextjs v12.3.0

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am applying the **Layout RFC** in my Next.js project.

I created a new `app/` folder from the root project folder to put the Layout RFC and every page component, but I can't access any segment in a URL path because it always conflicts with routing from the `pages/` folder, I noticed it always works with `pages/`.
Why this problem is going on? And how I can resolve it?

Comment: NextJs uses the default page folder for routing purposes, you need to import all the components you put in the ```app/``` folder inside your ```pages/``` folder

Comment: The Layout RFC is not yet available in Next.js.